# p:poll throws AbortProcessingException during wildfly restart

Tags: primefaces, wildfly

In the jsf code I use a Primefaces p:poll to refresh the page and everything works fine.  Though, if the wildfly server is restarted while this page is already open the p:poll throws an AbortProcessingException .

```
<p:poll 
    interval="3" 
    listener="#{conferencePlatformMonitors.init}" 
    update="@form" />
```

I can replace the p:poll with a javascript to reload the page in the same interval and the i dont get any crashes if the page is open during a wildfly restart,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 3000);  
</script>
```

I would prefer to use p:poll than the javascript.  Im using Primefaces 6.0

This is the stacktrace

```
10:09:46,409 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-8) JSF1073: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException caught during processing of RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=java.lang.NullPointerException
10:09:46,410 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-8) java.lang.NullPointerException: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startMetadataIfNecessary(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:303)
        at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.redirect(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:156)
        at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext$OmniPartialResponseWriter.redirect(OmniPartialViewContext.java:426)
        at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext$OmniPartialResponseWriter.startDocument(OmniPartialViewContext.java:281)
        at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:306)
        at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
        at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:432)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:265)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:200)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:193)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:106)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletFormAuthenticationMechanism.servePage(ServletFormAuthenticationMechanism.java:102)
        at io.undertow.security.impl.FormAuthenticationMechanism.sendChallenge(FormAuthenticationMechanism.java:172)
        at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$ChallengeSender.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:283)
        at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$ChallengeSender.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:302)
        at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$ChallengeSender.access$300(SecurityContextImpl.java:266)
        at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.sendChallenges(SecurityContextImpl.java:125)
        at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authTransition(SecurityContextImpl.java:99)
        at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authTransition(SecurityContextImpl.java:104)
        at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authenticate(SecurityContextImpl.java:89)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:55)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.primefaces.util.ResourceUtils.filterStylesheets(ResourceUtils.java:96)
        at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startMetadataIfNecessary(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:287)
        ... 62 more
```

Comment: This is  comparing apples and oranges. Why do you need p:poll

Comment: Because the prime faces p poll updates the component much cleaner.  The javascript makes the screen actually flicker just a bit when the page reloads.  The poll doesn't flicker and looks better.  These are 2 different ways to reload content on the screen.  Not actually apples and oranges. Anyway helpful suggestions would be appreciated.  :)

Comment: Both fruit in that they refresh a page. But they work completely different. One is just doing a new get for a page (which might even just be reloaded from the cache!), the other explicitly calls java methods in your code via ajax (apples and oranges). Try increasing the poll interval and shutting down the server between two requests, no errors then most likely. These errors are not easily to prevent other then maybe using an ajax exceptionhandler and trying to ignore this. Or see if you can configure wildfly to stop accepting new requests, first handle existing requests and then shutdown.

Comment: I would personally not worry about this error, the same will occur if it is in the middle of processing an action(listener) from a click on a button.